# Filtering JSON Object and outputting another

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse a JSON file which looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "id": "539eebdba276db40a4716726",
        "name": "Development Task",
        "idList": "539eebbb4e9a8d709704b254",
        "desc": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "539eebe09b42c971d46b9ba1",
        "name": "Design Task",
        "idList": "539eebbe50dc4fa2a82474fc",
        "desc": "",
        "url": ""
    }
]
```

I'm trying to get the `desc` object from the array with the name `Development Task`, the system needs to be dynamic so I can't just use `json_o[0](desc);`

I've tried different methods such as foreaching the data multiple times but I still can't think of a solution, any help would be great, cheers.

Comment: You should get like that `$json_o[0]['desc'];` after decoded `$json_o = json_decode($jsonstring, true);`

Comment: @Bora, how can you say, it is the first element of the array and can be accessed through 0th index, as OP clearly mentioned `the system needs to be dynamic so I can't just use json_o[0](desc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for dynamic fields, i would have gone with :

```
$jsonData = '[
    {
        "id": "539eebdba276db40a4716726",
        "name": "Development Task",
        "idList": "539eebbb4e9a8d709704b254",
        "desc": "FirstDescription",
        "url": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "539eebe09b42c971d46b9ba1",
        "name": "Design Task",
        "idList": "539eebbe50dc4fa2a82474fc",
        "desc": "SecondDescription",
        "url": ""
    }
]';

$arrayFromJson = json_decode($jsonData, true);

function searchByKey($keyToSearchIn, $searchName, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[$keyToSearchIn] == $searchName) {
           return $val['desc'];
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$return = searchByKey("name", "Development Task", $arrayFromJson);
```

So

```
var_dump($return);
```

returns

```
string(16) "FirstDescription"
```

Note : If you only need a search by name, you can change the function with :

```
function searchByName( $searchName, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['name'] == $searchName) {
           return $val['desc'];
       }
   }
   return null;
}

$return = searchByName("Development Task", $arrayFromJson);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$jsonData = '[
    {
        "id": "539eebdba276db40a4716726",
        "name": "Development Task",
        "idList": "539eebbb4e9a8d709704b254",
        "desc": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "539eebe09b42c971d46b9ba1",
        "name": "Design Task",
        "idList": "539eebbe50dc4fa2a82474fc",
        "desc": "",
        "url": ""
    }
]';

$encoded = json_decode($jsonData);

foreach($encoded as $data) 
{
        if('Development Task' == $data->name) 
        {
            echo $data->desc;
        }
}
```

Comment: Close, but he's asking for `desc` from the first record, not an iteration

Comment: Just now edited :) check the update and thanks for pointing. I didnt notice, OP need the description where name is `Development Task`.

Comment: @Machavity & @Bora, yes got your point, but OP need the description, where name is `Development Task` and OP's code is dynamic and OP does not even know whether it will be the first element of the array or last :). That's why we have to have a loop and check where name is `Development Task`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments in the code explain what happens:

```
    $jsonData = '[
    {
        "id": "539eebdba276db40a4716726",
        "name": "Development Task",
        "idList": "539eebbb4e9a8d709704b254",
        "desc": "moocow",
        "url": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "539eebe09b42c971d46b9ba1",
        "name": "Design Task",
        "idList": "539eebbe50dc4fa2a82474fc",
        "desc": "wowcow",
        "url": ""
    },
        {
        "id": "539eebe09rb42c971d46b9ba1",
        "name": "Development Task",
        "idList": "539eebbe50dc4fa2a82474fc",
        "desc": "sowccow",
        "url": ""
    }
]';

$encoded = json_decode($jsonData, true); //converts the json object to an array
foreach ($encoded as $arrayObject){
  if( in_array("Development Task", $arrayObject) ){
    print_r($arrayObject['desc'] . "\n");
  }
}
-> moocow sowccow
```

based upon

> I'm trying to get the desc object from the array with the name Development Task

This should do what you want and you can easily take the string and make it a variable. There are plenty of built-in functions on PHP.net that are tuned and are probably 10x better than rolling your own code.

Comment: imo and 'nitpicking', 'in_array' would be slightly clearer as to what is required from the test as only existence of the value is required. i.e. if (in_array( "Development Task", $arrayObject)) {

Comment: Ah this is true, and I wouldn't need to explicitly check for T/F.